How to Display All Repetitive Digits from a String ? in vb.Net
String = 24-06-1966
repetitive Nos to be displayed 6, 6, 6
Non-Repetitive Nos to be displayed 2, 4, 1, 9
Hello
If someone can help me to get or displayed Repetitive digits from Numeric String
   TxtBxString.Text ="24-06-1966"
    TxtBxRepetitive.Text ="6, 6, 6"
    Textbox1.Text =  "2, 4, 1, 9"


Your help shall be appreciated
Thanks
SsD
2.
Oliver I did not understand your statement
First I think i Should Replace "-", ""
Therefore i used the following
Dim replacedStr As String = TxtBxString.Text.Replace("-", "")

Then to Split the above replacedStr with the below coding adopted from this forums thread 38690124 but is no use for me as the coding for VBA excel
and not vb.net
Also the line starting with Redim digits gave me Error
'ReDim' statements can no longer be used to declare array variables
and therfore To Check in Textbox1.Text or Msgbox could not get result of Splited string. So How Correctly can i derive this ?
Sub SplitLong()

    Dim digits() As Long
    Dim intValue As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strValue As String

    'intValue = 123456789
    'strValue = intValue
     strvalue = TxtBxString.Text

    ReDim digits(Len(strValue) - 1) As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(strValue)
        digits(i - 1) = Mid$(strValue, i, 1)
    Next
End Sub

Hope this is correct logic ? if not your help will be appreciated
Thanks
SsD

What have you done and where are you stuck? It's not for us to just write your code for you. Put some effort into thinking through the logic and then implementing that in code.

This looks like homework. You can access the strings characters (type char) with an index s[i]. Use an int[] array of length ten to store the count of every digit.

Why is "0" omitted from the result?

Why is "0" omitted from the result?
Andrew 0 or Zero needs to be  completely ignored

How can i add new post to this thread. Am Confussed it seems  writing comments is too limited

@SsD If you [edit] your question you can add the information requested in comments to it. Then people with enough rep may vote to re-open the question.

@SsD I suggest that you try doing it with pencil and paper. Once you have figured out an algorithm, you can write some code to do the same thing.

Repeats: Dim r = String.Join("; ", s.Where(Function(c) Char.IsNumber(c) AndAlso c <> "0"c).GroupBy(Function(c) c).Select(Function(g) (g.Key, g.Count())).Where(Function(t) t.Count > 1).Select(Function(t) String.Join(", ", Enumerable.Repeat(t.Key, t.Count)))), Singles: Dim o = String.Join(", ", s.Where(Function(c) Char.IsNumber(c) AndAlso c <> "0"c).GroupBy(Function(c) c).Select(Function(g) (g.Key, g.Count())).Where(Function(t) t.Count = 1).Select(Function(t) t.Key))

Djv : Really Superb Thank you so much for Differentiating Repeats and Singles. BTW what are t.key, g.Key

Here is my attempt (I replaced the textboxes with strings for testing, but it's the same):
    Dim TxtBxString_Text As String = "24-06-1966"
    Dim TxtBxRepetitive_Text, Textbox1_Text As String

    Dim count As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9 'Check every possible digit. If u don't want "0", set "i as integer = 1 to 9"
        If TxtBxString_Text.Contains(i.ToString) Then 'Check if the digit is in the original string
            count = TxtBxString_Text.Count(Function(c) c = i.ToString) 'how many times "i" is written?
            If count > 1 Then 'It's a repetitive char
                For j As Integer = 0 To count - 1
                    TxtBxRepetitive_Text += i.ToString + ", "
                Next
            Else 'It's a single char
                Textbox1_Text += i.ToString + ", "
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MessageBox.Show("TxtBxRepetitive.Text= " + TxtBxRepetitive_Text + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Textbox1.Text= " + Textbox1_Text)

The result will be:


count = TxtBxString_Text.Count(Function(c) c = i.ToString)

The above syntax has minor error
0 Error on i.ToString
Warning BC42324
Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results.
Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable.

It's just a warning... You can remove this warning by storing i.toString() in a new variable. So, delete count = TxtBxString_Text.Count(Function(c) c = i.ToString), add a new string variable like Dim a As String = i.ToString and then rewrite the deleted line this way: count = TxtBxString_Text.Count(Function(c) c = a).

Oh Ok So this is how one overcomes the error Thank you so much

@SsD Glad to have been helpful! If my answer has solved your problem, you can select it as "accepted" by clicking on the "v" button to the left of my answer :D
